# React.FunctionComponent with generics in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-functional-component

I'm creating a component that takes an arbitrary list of values and a transformer that will render a specific value. The values can be of any type, as the rendering is handler by the transformer, but the compiler is complaining about the generics parameter.

Here is a minimal example:

```js
interface MyListParams<T> {
  values: T[];
  transformer: (value: T) => JSX.Element
}

export const MyList: React.FunctionComponent<MyListParam<T>> = ({

}) => <>
    {values.map(transformer)}
  </>
```

This code gives me the error `Cannot find name 'T'.` in code `React.FunctionComponent<MyListParam<T>>`.

I do realize that I have to tell typescript that this function is using generics, but I fail to find the correct place to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to pass a `type` to the component when using `React.FC`, so you can try:

```
interface MyListParams<T> {
    values: T[];
    transformer: (value: T) => JSX.Element;
}
  
const MyList = <T extends object>(props: PropsWithChildren<MyListParams<T>>) => <></>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The generics is on the interface - meaning you want to reuse the interface.

In your example you are using the interface so you need to specify its type:

```
// T is string
export const MyList: React.FunctionComponent<MyListParams<string>> = ({
values, transformer
}) => <>{values.map(transformer)}</>
```

If the generics on the function see [official examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types) (not a real use case in function component).